# Java, out of memory, inefficient function

Tags: java, memory

I'm writing a program that is supposed to create chains of numbers and see witch one is the longest. The problem is that I run out of memory and I have no idea what eats all of the memory. Does anyone know were the problem is?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> longestchain;
    ArrayList<Integer> chain = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int size = 0;
    int longestsize = 0;
    int start;
    int number = 0;

        for(int i = 3; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            start = i;
            chain.clear();
            chain.add(start);
            size = 1;
            while(true)
            {
                if(start == 1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if(iseven(start))
                {
                    start = start / 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    start = start*3 + 1;
                }

                chain.add(start);
                size++;

            }

            if(size > longestsize)
            {
                longestsize = size;
                longestchain = chain;
                number = i;

            }
            //System.out.println(i);

        }
        System.out.println(number + ". " + longestsize);

}

public static boolean iseven(int n)
{
    return (n % 2 == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem is that when `i=113383` you're running into an integer overflow.** This results in an infinite loop that keeps adding to `chain` until you run out of heap space. Change `chain` and `longestchain` to `ArrayList<Long>`, `start` to `long` and `iseven()` to take `long`, and you'll solve that particular problem.

Another problem is that `longestchain = chain` assigns the reference, whereas you need to copy the contents. Otherwise the next iteration will wipe `longestchain`.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not be the solution, but a hint:

The default array size for an ArrayList is 10. Initialize your ArrayLists to a value closer to what you are expecting, or many array creations happen under the hood:

```
// e.g.
ArrayList<Integer> chain = new ArrayList<Integer>(50000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why are you running out of memory, but I noticed a bug in your code - longestchain and chain point to the same object, so when you clear chain, you also clear longestchain. You can fix it by creating a new array with contents of chain instead of an assignment.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice I made that misstake.